# how to use DescriptorMatcher of FLANNBASED in opencv version "3.0.0"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv3.0

Syntax for calling flannbased descriptorMatcher in opencv "3.0.0"..

I used below code to call flannbased descriptorMatcher in opencv "3.4.6"..

Ptr matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(DescriptorMatcher::FLANNBASED);

error shown while compiling with opencv "3.0.0"

" error C2039: 'FLANNBASED' : is not a member of 'cv::DescriptorMatcher' "

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the problem myself. Problem was only in spelling of "FlannBased" instead of "`FLANNBASED`".

```
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
```